# In Perl, how to get the number that occurs BEFORE a specific word?

Tags: string, perl, integer, cpu-word

suppose I have the string:

`my $SENTENCE = "get schwifty for 7 days"`

-...and I want to figure out the number of days. how could I get the number 7 from this if i know it will ALWAYS come before the word day/days?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex with a capture group:

```
$SENTENCE =~ /(\d+) days?/;
my $days = $1;
```

Comment: You should check the return value of the regex before trusting `$1`. Or better: `my ($days) = $SENTENCE =~ /(\d+) days?/`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to capture the digit

```
my ($day) = $sentence =~ /(\d+)Days?/g;
```

Or else another way for group the word with in pattern match by using `(?{})`

```
$Sentence =~ /(\d+)Days?(?{my $day = $1})/g:
```

Answer (score 0):

use Look-ahead property and get your number of days

```
my $SENTENCE = "get schwifty for 7 days";
($num) = $SENTENCE =~m/(\d+)(?=\s+days?)/;
print $num;
```